# Integrating angular js with existing javaScript code

Tags: angularjs, html

We are working on pure javaScript project, which could really benefit by using  angular js but it's a huge project and re-writing the whole project in angular is not an option  .  Does anyone have any idea or advice about integrating angular with an existing project

Comment: Yeah, re-write the project. Unless you build a proper angular foundation, integration will just give you a bad time and bad code.

Comment: I'd really advise against that, you will deal with more problems than you gain while integrating. Angular is really an ecosystem itself, it does not play well with others.

Answer (score 0):

Angular is a framework. It's all or nothing...you are going to rewrite everything just due to the nature of how Angular works. You can't really just 'sprinkle' some Angular on top of it because Angular controls the entire view.

It may be possible to just use Angular in a certain area of the page, but this would be a huge waste of resources (Angular minified is 143K) and make for terrible code.